Сделать знаки "Альтруист" и "Благодетель" золотыми или серебряным
Есть бронзовые знаки Альтруист и Благодетель, у них 128 и 680 награждений. Но у некоторых серебряных/золотых знаков награждений куда больше: у знака Известный вопрос есть более 28 тысяч награждений. Поэтому нужно сделать те знаки золотыми или серебряными.

Этот вопрос за пределами компетенций нашего сайта. Его стоит задать на MSE, так как изменение повлияет на все сайты сети Stack Exchange.

@aepot, но обсудить-то можно ;)

Понятно........
